# Linq where clause in select new

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables let's call them t1 and t2.
t1 has an ID, a string and a boolean. t2 has an ID, a date and a t1.ID.
I want to put them in a List of my class.

```
public class MyClass {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date1 {get; set;}
    public Datetime Date2 {get; set;}
}
```

(it has 15 dates, to keep it smaller I just put two in there)

I was able to find a solution :

```
List<MyClass> list = (from t2 in con.t2
                      join t1 in con.t1 on t2.T1ID equals t1.ID
                      select t2).GroupBy(d => d.T1ID).Select(x => new MyClass()
{
    Name = x.FirstOrDefault().t1.Name,
    Date1 = x.where(d => d.ID == 1).SingleOrDefault().Date,
    Date2 = x.where(d => d.ID == 2).SingleOrDefault().Date
}).ToList();
```

It is working as expected, but the problem is, I'm getting this warning from visual studio:

> The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([t2].T1ID)' could not be translated and
>   will be evaluated locally.

It appears several times. This message comes for SingleOrDefault too. I tested a little bit around and it just comes if I put the where in the select new.

So how do I change my expression to avoid that? Or is my expression crap and I could've done it much better? (I can't change the table structure)

Comment: This is due to EF Core not "knowing" yet how to translate that to SQL. The EF Core team is improving this on each version, however a lot of things are still evaluated in memory. Pay attention to that warning because evaluating thing in memory can cause you to allocate a lot of memory and having big performance issues as tables grow. If you can't rewrite the query in a way that EF core can translate it to SQL, you can use [Raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) feature from EF Core

Comment: @Tyimi generating JOINs is the job of the ORM. Using LINQ like this is a clear sign that there are missing relations between the entities. ORMs aren't meant for reporting scenarios either.

Comment: @TYimi what are you trying to do with this query? It would look rather weird even in SQL. It looks like the JOIN returns way more rows than needed so you have to use `First` and `Single` to remove duplicates. Why not write a single `SELECT Name,ID,MIN(DATE) FROM T2 WHERE ID IN (1,2) GROUP BY Name,ID` ? The JOIN seems to exist simply to return only rows that exist in the other table

Comment: I want to get the dates for the IDs in t1 in one row. The ID in t2 isn't a real ID since it isn't unique. So every row in T1 has 15 dates in T2 with the IDs 1-15.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is still a limitation of EF. Just pay attention to the memory used by your queries because the warning is alerting you to do so.

Regards.

Comment: It's about 350 rows. Won't be much more in future.

Comment: @Tyimi the query would look weird even in SQL. Explain what you try to accomplish with it. Most likely there are far easier ways to write it. 350 sounds a lot like a date-related query too.